# IBM RTC Logging SDK in Java with Spring Boot

Tags: java, sdk, spring-boot, rtc

When using the RTC SDK normally in an application, I can turn off the logging in that layer using Log4j with the following code:

```
// Only show warnings for IBM dependencies
Logger.getLogger("com.ibm").setLevel(Level.WARN);
Logger.getLogger("com.ibm").setAdditivity(false);
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

When trying to convert over to SpringBoot, I add just the basic SpringBoot package and I get all sorts of debug information from the RTC SDK. Even if I have only the root logger set to FATAL and have not settings anywhere else for logging.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

As soon as I add the dependency, (without even having the @SpringBootApplication annotation or even SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args), it starts spewing out RTC log information like the following:

```
16:14:20.161 [main] DEBUG c.i.t.r.c.i.u.InternalTeamPlatform - Thread[main,5,main]
16:14:20.164 [main] DEBUG c.i.t.r.c.i.u.InternalTeamPlatform - start asBundlefalse
16:14:20.164 [main] DEBUG c.i.t.r.c.i.u.InternalTeamPlatform - set start true
16:14:22.387 [main] DEBUG c.i.t.r.t.client.RemoteTeamServer - Entering setCredentials(userid=, password=)
16:14:22.387 [main] DEBUG c.i.t.r.t.client.RemoteTeamServer - Entering closeHttpClient
16:14:22.387 [main] DEBUG c.i.t.r.t.client.RemoteTeamServer - Value of _httpclient: null
16:14:22.408 [main] DEBUG c.i.t.r.t.client.RemoteTeamServer - httpclient already closed
16:14:22.410 [main] DEBUG c.i.t.r.t.client.RemoteTeamServer - Entering createTeamService
16:14:22.410 [main] DEBUG c.i.t.r.t.client.RemoteTeamServer - creating RemoteTeamService from com.ibm.team.repository.common.internal.IRepositoryRemoteService
16:14:22.420 [main] DEBUG c.i.t.r.t.client.RemoteTeamServer - Entering createTeamService
16:14:22.420 [main] DEBUG c.i.t.r.t.client.RemoteTeamServer - creating RemoteTeamService from com.ibm.team.repository.common.service.IQueryService
16:14:22.424 [main] DEBUG c.i.t.r.t.client.RemoteTeamServer - Entering createTeamService
16:14:22.424 [main] DEBUG c.i.t.r.t.client.RemoteTeamServer - creating RemoteTeamService from com.ibm.team.repository.common.service.IExternalUserRegistryService
```

My question is, how can I turn this excess logging off? It is quite annoying and not useful to me.

Comment: Apparently you have to include this inside of your pom underneath the dependency tag:
     `<exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my colleague suggested in his comment:

you have to include this inside of your pom underneath the dependency tag:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```